# Loading CSV file having json data fails using copy command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to load CSV file into snowflake table:

File has contents of type:

```
id^country_name^country_iso^completness^spelling^lang^writejson^updation_time^temp_email^pro^content_duplication^bla^email_duplication^ip_duplication^is_suspicious^plagiarism^score_updated_on^reviewer_id_duplication^campaign_status^campaign_ineligibility_reason^is_enrichment_completed^referrer_eligibility_status^referrer_ineligibility_reason
com___1000525^India^IN^{'Stars': 1.0, 'BaseScore': 0.18564370805147765, 'Score': 0.12995059563603434, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 3}^^{'Languages': [{'Name': 'en', 'Score': 12.58, 'IsReliable': True}], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 0, 'CheckType': 1}^^2022-04-25 17:19:31.836724+00:00^{'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 0, 'CheckType': 4}^{'proWords': [], 'Count': 0, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 5}^{'DuplicatedEntities': [], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 6}^{'TestsBreakdown': {'MarkovChain': 0.0, 'WordDensity': 0.0, 'UniqueCharRatio': 0.0, 'WordCharRatio': 0.0, 'WordsTrigram': 0.0}, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 7}^{'DuplicatedIds': ['com___1001137', 'DM___463789', 'com___2397341', 'com___1769060', 'com___2510329', 'com___2078867', 'com___2078795', 'com___1467866', 'com___1619447', 'com___2139946', 'com___1282623', 'com___1618676', 'DM___501990', 'com___1618293', 'com___86256', 'com___2382378', 'com___427842', 'com___2125700', 'com___123225', 'com___119985', 'com___64533', 'DM___2127218', 'com___1177691', 'com___101523', 'com___1305194', 'com___2126558', 'com___1335365', 'DM___1435503', 'com___186074', 'com___166337'], 'Count': 30, 'Score': 0.0, 'Version': 2, 'CheckType': 8}^{'Results': {'365.00:00:00': 0, '7.00:00:00': 0, '1.00:00:00': 0, '02:00:00': 0}, 'Total': 0, 'DuplicatedEntities': [], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 3, 'CheckType': 9}^0^{'ModeratorReviewUri': 'http://view.copyscape.com/search/bt5zh2oywv', 'PlagiarismSources': [], 'PlagiarismSourcesCount': 0, 'AllWordsMatched': 0, 'AllPercentMatched': 0, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 10}^2022-04-25 17:19:31.836724+00:00^{'DuplicatedIds': [], 'Count': 0, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 2, 'CheckType': 11}^^^True^^
com___1000740^India of America^IN^{'Stars': 3.0, 'BaseScore': 0.5898570386525455, 'Score': 0.5898570386525455, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 3}^^{'Languages': [{'Name': 'en', 'Score': 13.99, 'IsReliable': True}], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 0, 'CheckType': 1}^^2022-04-25 17:19:49.545032+00:00^{'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 0, 'CheckType': 4}^{'proWords': [], 'Count': 0, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 5}^{'DuplicatedEntities': [], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 6}^{'TestsBreakdown': {'MarkovChain': 0.0, 'WordDensity': 0.0, 'UniqueCharRatio': 0.0, 'WordCharRatio': 0.0, 'WordsTrigram': 0.0}, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 7}^{'DuplicatedIds': ['com___2372922', 'com___1239154', 'com___566274', 'com___1850105', 'DM___464273'], 'Count': 5, 'Score': 0.6666666666666667, 'Version': 2, 'CheckType': 8}^{'Results': {'365.00:00:00': 0, '7.00:00:00': 0, '1.00:00:00': 0, '02:00:00': 0}, 'Total': 0, 'DuplicatedEntities': [], 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 3, 'CheckType': 9}^4^{'ModeratorReviewUri': 'http://view.copyscape.com/search/e6beugtohf', 'PlagiarismSources': [], 'PlagiarismSourcesCount': 0, 'AllWordsMatched': 0, 'AllPercentMatched': 0, 'Score': 1.0, 'Version': 1, 'CheckType': 10}^2022-04-25 17:19:49.545032+00:00^{'DuplicatedIds': ['com___1239154', 'com___2372922', 'com___566274', 'com___1850105'], 'Count': 4, 'Score': 0.7333333333333334, 'Version': 2, 'CheckType': 11}^^^True^^
```

JSON is getting stored as varchar in snowflake

I am loading data into a CSV file into snowflake using code and it fails at copy command.

```
df.to_csv(fp, index=False, sep='^', columns=columns)

self.connection.execute(
                f"COPY INTO {table_name} FROM @{stage_name} PURGE = TRUE "
                f"FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = '^' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\"' "
                f"ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None error_on_column_count_mismatch=false SKIP_HEADER = 1)")
```

It is failing with error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100069 (22P02): Error parsing JSON: {'MistakesCount': 1, 'MistakePercents': 0.038461538461538464, 'MistakenTokens': [{'Offset': 83, 'Toke
  File 'cdvfile.csv.gz', line 34, character 145
  Row 33, column "TABLE1650968127"["spelling":5]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
[SQL: COPY INTO reviews_enrichments_test_temp1650968127 FROM @reviews_enrichments_test_temp1650968127_og02fua2 PURGE = TRUE FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'CSV' field_delimiter = '^' FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None error_on_column_count_mismatch=false SKIP_HEADER = 1)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

can you tell me what causes this error? thanks

Comment: Hi = just to clarify, when you say "loading data into a CSV file" I assume you mean loading data from a csv file into a Snowflake table? Also, do you mean that the csv file has been populated from postgres - in which case that is presumably a separate process and therefore is not relevant to the issue you are having loading data from a csv file into a Snowflake table? Can you update your question with the data from your csv file that is causing the issue, so from roughly rows 30 to 40 (obfuscating any sensitive data, obviously)?

Comment: Use below command to get more about the error of the record:
select * from table(validate(t1, job_id => '_last'));

Where the job_id is the query id of the copy command.

Comment: @NickW I have added sample data

Comment: The quote character used in JSON is `"` not `'` (well, at least in postgresql implementation of it--I assume in snowflake as well)  Also, snowflake is not postgresql, what about this question pertains to postgresql?